# Set cookie by php session username

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cookies

I have set a general cookie that works fine for a run once situation. However, what I need to do is set a cookie by username so a message is displayed only once per user. I am using php to set a session for the username linked to mysql.

I have posted the code I am using for the general cookie and wonder if it can be modified to target a username rather than a general cookie.

I would be grateful if someone could help with this. Thanks

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  if (document.cookie.indexOf("runOnce") < 0) {
    $("#message3").dialog({
      modal: true,

      buttons: {
        'Confirm': function() {
            document.cookie = 'runOnce = true; expires = Fri, 31 Dec 9999 23:59:59 GMT; path = /';
            $(this).dialog("close");
          }
          /* ,
          No: function () {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" ); 
          }*/

      }
    });

    // Hide the close button
    jQuery("a.ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide();

    //Disable the confirm button on page load
    $(":button:contains('Confirm')").attr("disabled", true).addClass("ui-state-disabled");

    // Uncheck the 'agree' checkbox
    $(function() {
      $('#message3 input[type=checkbox]').attr('checked', false);
    });

    // Hide red message paragraph
    $('#agreemsg').hide();

    // Function to enable and disable confirm button based on checkbox click event
    $("#checkme").click(function() {

      var isChecked = $("#checkme").is(":checked");

      if (isChecked) {

        //alert("CheckBox checked.");
        $(":button:contains('Confirm')").removeAttr('disabled').removeClass('ui-state-disabled');
        $('#agreemsg').show();

      } else {
        //alert("CheckBox not checked.");
        $(":button:contains('Confirm')").prop("disabled", true).addClass("ui-state-disabled");
        $('#agreemsg').hide();
      }
    });
    //}
  };
});
</script>
```

Comment: The only thing that would differ would be the name of the cookie, so you can identify it. You'll require the username itself, which is public anyway so that's not a problem. I see you're using jQuery. All you have to do is `$.cookie('cookie_name', 'value')`.

Comment: I think you would be much better off saving the run once per user in your database on the first login or load of the page and sending that information to browser otherwise it will run once per user per browser or even more often if they use private browsing or delete their cookies.

Comment: I don't see any php here

Comment: @Loren has a very good point. It's much safer that way. However, consider than on each request you're doing 1 extra db query. Which is not ideal.

Comment: *"I am using php to set a session for the username linked to mysql."* - How do we know if something in there isn't failing also?

Comment: @Andrew not necessarily each request.  Once it has been set as true, that could be remembered in the session the asker already has.  It is only necessary to check when it is assumed to be false.  If this is run right after login, it could be checked at the same time as the session is originally populated.

Answer (score 0):

Cookies are not the correct place to implement this. It's best to add additional property in the database associated with your user, for example:

Table: users

Columns:

```
id
username
... other fields ...
is_first_login
```

1. Display your message if is_first_login is not true
2. Mark is_first_login to true in the database after your message has been displayed